# Use of Filters before controller in Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, symfony, events

I wanted to open a new browser window before arriving on the application.

I have to say that before arriving to the application, there is an authentication. If the authentication is good, it may go to the DefaultController/indexAction.

First, in my DefaultController indexAction I wrote this :

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');

if($kernel->getEnvironment() === 'prod' && $session->has('full_screen')) {
   $session->set('full_screen', 'done');
   return $this->render('MyBundle::index.js.twig');
```

}

```
 ... the code of my action
```

in index.js.twig, there is this code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var settings = "width=" + 
        (screen.width - (screen.width * 0.005))  + ", height=" + 
        ((screen.height - (screen.height * 0.050))) + 
        " , top=0, left=0, scrollbars=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, \n\
            menubar=no, toolbar=no, resizable=no, dependent=no";
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
win = window.open('{{path('app_index')}}', 'APPLICATION_NAME', settings);
win.focus();
</script>
```

Note : route app_index goes to DefaultController/indexAction

This is working good.

The problem is that the code is inside the indexAction of the controller. So I decided to use a beforeController event to do it.
So the code in the indexAction is out.

I create an interface :

```
interface IWindowController {
    public function openWindowAction();
```

}

Now DefaultController implements the interface and I have to add a new method 'openWindowAction' which is just this :

```
public function openWindowAction() {
    return $this->render('MyLBundle::index.js.twig');
}
```

I create a listener like this :

```
class WindowListener {
private $kernel;
private $session;

function __construct($kernel, Session $session) {
    $this->kernel = $kernel;
    $this->session = $session;
}

public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if($controller[0] instanceof IWindowController) {        
        if($this->kernel->getEnvironment() === 'dev' && !$this->session->has('full_screen')) {
            $this->session->set('full_screen', 'done');
            $controller[0]->openWindowAction();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And add WindowListener to services.yml :

```
my.window.listener:
    class: PATH\TO\WindowListener
    arguments: [@kernel, @session]
    tags: 
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Debugging the program, it goes to the listener, it calls and goes to the openWindowActionMethod in the controller. But it is like the render does not render anything. an alert in the javascript is not displayed.

SO there is no window opening, the application is displayed in the same window.

Why is that ? How can I make it work ?

MODIFICATION :

I modified services.yml to add twig engine injection.

```
arguments: [@kernel, @session, @templating]
```

Modified constructor in WindowListener.

```
private $kernel;
private $session;
private $twig_engine;

function __construct($kernel, Session $session, TwigEngine $templating) {
    $this->kernel = $kernel;
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->twig_engine = $templating;
}
```

and modified the end of onKernelController method

```
$this->session->set('full_screen', 'done');
//$controller[0]->openWindowAction();
return $this->twig_engine->render('MyBundle::index.js.twig');
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: Think about it.  openWindowAction returns a response.  What happens to it in your listener?  Not much.  You are close but reread the section on kernel listeners.  You actually want to listen to KernelEvents::REQUEST which allows you to return an actual response object.  No need for a controller at all.  Inject the twig engine for rendering.  And don't inject the session.  The event has the request object.  Get the session from it.  Don't think you need the entire kernel just to get the environment either.  Pretty sure there is a parameter.

Comment: Can I have some code ?

Comment: I don't have time to post a mostly working solution for you at the moment.  Maybe someone else will step in?  But really what you have is almost there.  Just need to inject the twig template engine and add your response to the event.  Examine the render method in the base controller class to see how.  If you get stuck then update your question with the new code.